# How to remove the square brackets in output of the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
items=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
print("The first 3 items in the list are: ")
for item in items[:3]:
    print(item)

#or
print("The first 3 items in the list are: " + str(items[:3]))
```

Q: How should I make the output of the 'first 3 items' to be horizontal(like the second code) but without the square brackets(like the 1st code)?

Comment: Please clarify *but without the square brackets* since the first part does not print any square brackets.

Comment: @rahulrachh `print(item, end=',')` means that the last item in the list would also be followed by a comma. This is not what people usually want.

Comment: @schneebuzz  first code displays a list, it doesn't have [ ]. And I expected the output to be "without the [ ]" = just to be like the first code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), where `str` is the separator between the items in the `iterable`. For example:

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
print('The first 3 items in the list are: ' + ', '.join(items[:3]))
```

This prints:

```
The first 3 items in the list are: a, b, c
```

In this case, `', '` is the separator between the items of the list. You can change it according to your needs. For example, using `' '.join(items[:3])` instead would result in:

```
The first 3 items in the list are: a b c
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. The appropriate here (IMO) is to use

```
print("items are: " + ', '.join(items[:3]))
```

Which (depending on your python version) can be simplified to:

```
print(f'items are: {", ".join(items[:3])}')
```

*or without the comma*

Another way is to tell the `print` to not print linebreaks:

```
for item in items[:3]:
    print(item, end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write `print(item, end=" ")` in your loop.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will print a space after the last item printed.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
print("The first 3 items in the list are: " + str(items[:3])[1:-1])
```

assuming you don't mind the items separated by commas.